# Why aren't WPF controls private by default?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, writing

```
<TextBlock x:Name="foo"/>
```

will make the control `public`. To make it `private`, one must explicitly specify the `FieldModifier`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="foo" x:FieldModifier="private"/>
```

I find this strange. I don't think it is a good coding style to access a subcontrol directly from outside the class. For example, I would avoid writing

```
var muc = new MyUserControl();
muc.foo.Text = "foo";
```

Instead I would write a public method and use it:

```
public void SetFooText(string text) { foo.Text = text; }
```

```
// in somewhere else
var muc = new MyUserControl();
muc.SetFooText("foo");
```

or write a public property

```
public string FooText 
{ 
    get { return foo.Text; } 
    set { foo.Text = value; } 
}
```

```
// in somewhere else
var muc = new MyUserControl();
muc.FooText = "foo";
```

So, I don't really see any advantages setting controls to `public` by default. Maybe it would be safer if `private` is the default, like everything in C#.

Why is `public` the default?

### Edit:

Well, I made a mistake. The default is `internal` as others have mentioned. But the question why it is not `private` is still waiting for an answer.

Comment: I'm interested in an answer but afaik Microsoft has never given rationale for this. Given that databinding eliminates the need for a field in 99% of cases, one would think the default would be to simply not create a field, while still making it available for databinding by name in XAML.

Comment: They seem to be internal. not public. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8eadc3a2-8faa-4149-91ad-34356deb42a9/do-xaml-elements-default-to-internal?forum=wpf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default value of the x:FieldModifier for C# is NotPublic(Internal)

> TypeAttributes.NotPublic is the default behavior because it is infrequent that code outside the assembly that compiled the XAML needs access to a XAML-created element. WPF security architecture together with XAML compilation behavior will not declare fields that store element instances as public, unless you specifically set the x:FieldModifier to allow public access.

As we see if they were private by default assembly which compiled the XAML would not have access to it XAML-created element.

You can find more information here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970905(v=vs.110).aspx)